# Set Angular 7 environment in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to configure Angular 7 environment in Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2017 with an ASP.NET MVC project and also run from Visual Studio.

Comment: you must be used angular with system.js. and build this and ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following steps:

Step1. Create a folder “Angular App” inside your MVC application structure.

Step2. Create Angular application structure may be like:

o   App

   Modules
•   Module1
•   Module2
   Common
   Services

o   Webpack-config.js

o   Tsconfig.json

o   Enviorment.json

o   Package.json

Step2. Use Webpack to build your angular application.

Step3. Output of your build create bundle of Js file(s), include your bundled js and css file in. cshtml layout page.

Step4. Place your module startup angular selector in. cshtml page wherever you would like to bootstrap your angular application.

Comment: but what happens when we publish?is this use the same procedure to publish as we ASP.NET MVC application is publish

Comment: Yes, You will publish your ASP.NET MVC application and build your angular code  separately using prod flags. Once you  done with prod build of Angular code just put  all your bundled files to a folder and link these JS files again in your layout.cshtml